# Spark : Cassandra How to use a query to fetch data from cassandra with pyspark

Tags: cassandra, pyspark

I want to pass query as argument but it is giving following error.

> url = 'jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9042/tutorialspoint'
>       query = 'select * from emp LIMIT 10'

```
#.option("driver", "com.dbschema.CassandraJdbcDriver")\
df = spark_sql_context.read.format('jdbc')\
               .option("driver", "com.dbschema.CassandraJdbcDriver")\
               .option("url",url)\
               .option("dbtable", query)\
               .option("numPartitions", 2) \
               .load()

java.sql.SQLException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:14 no viable alternative at input 'select' (SELECT * FROM [select]...)
    at com.dbschema.CassandraPreparedStatement.executeQuery(CassandraPreparedStatement.java:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
```

Comment: alternative to your method : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878798/access-cassandra-from-pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your query I'm giving this solution. It should work for almost all common `select` queries(not sure about joins). I'm splitting your query in multiple parts as mentioned below because that's one way I know to work with Cassandra. Also I've changed the driver used. Hope it will work for you !

```
       column_names = (query.split("SELECT")[1]).split("from")[0].strip().split(",")
       print(column_names)

       table_name = query.split("from")[1].split(" ")[1]
       print(table_name)

       if "where" in query:
           where_condition = query.split("WHERE")[1]
           print(where_condition)
           df = self.spark_sql_context.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
               .load(table=table_name, keyspace=self.__keyspace).select(column_names).where(where_condition)

       else:
           df = self.spark_sql_context.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
               .load(table=table_name, keyspace=self.__keyspace).select(column_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are done with Spark and Cassandra integration, you can access it like:

```
spark_sql_context.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="tablename", keyspace="keyspace name").load()
```

**Update:**

In Java, we can execute specific query like this:

```
public static List<Row> selectSectorHourlyCounterTotals(String sectorName) {
        Statement statement = 
                new SimpleStatement(select * from tablename where sector_name ="'"+sectorName+"' allow filtering");
        ResultSet resultSet = dbSession.execute(statement);
        return resultSet.all();
    }
```

You need to convert this to scala/python.

Comment: This will load full table..but i need to pass some specific query

Comment: @priyanshi, i have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: This is not with spark..i think... i have to connect with pyspark only